# Clickable Span not being set for multiple words

Tags: android, spannablestring, clickablespan

I don't know if there is an exact solution to my problem on SO, but I have been stuck in this for a long time and need to unblock myself.

I have a string "0000 111 222", and I need to set a link to it. My code to set it is like this.

```
spanManager.SpannableBuilder(text, link)
                .setColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(containerView.context, R.color.blue))
                    .setFontSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
                    .setClickableSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
                    override fun onClick(textView: View) {
                        onClicked.value = action
                    }

                    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                        super.updateDrawState(ds)
                        ds.isUnderlineText = false
                    }
                })
                .build()
```

where link and text both are "0000 111 222".

Now the

> setClickableSpan(object: ClickableSpan)

is defined as

```
fun setClickableSpan(clickableSpan: ClickableSpan): SpannableBuilder {
    for (span in spans) {
        spannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, span.start, span.end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
    return this
}
```

The variable set **span** is set by *SpannableBuilder(text, link)* constructor which is like this

```
fun getSpans(fullText: String, subText: String): Set<Span> {
    val spans = HashSet<Span>()
    if (fullText.isEmpty() || subText.isEmpty()) {
        return spans
    }

    val ft = fullText.toLowerCase()
    val st = subText.trim().toLowerCase()

    val fullSplit = ft.split(" ")
    val subSplit = st.split(" ")

    var startPosition = 0
    for (full in fullSplit) {
        for (sub in subSplit) {
            val subTrim = sub.trim()
            if (!full.contains(subTrim)) {
                continue
            }
            val index = startPosition + full.indexOf(subTrim)
            val span = Span.create(index, index + subTrim.length)
            spans.add(span)
        }
        startPosition += full.length + 1
    }
    return spans
}
```

It basically splices the link variable across space delimiters. So the function

> setClickableSpan(object: ClickableSpan)

has size of spans as 3 for "0000 111 222". setSpan is a function defined SpannableStringInternal library.

Now the problem is that the link is being set only for "0000" and not the whole string. Whereas color and font span is able to get set for the whole string. I can not find the cause for this behaviour. If anybody can point out what is wrong here and what could be the probably fix, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Um I didn't dive deep in your code, but if you just want your number to be clickable and take you to 'dial' screen, you can use `autoLink` attribute on the TextView.

Comment: Not really. I don't want to go to dialler. I'm hoping to launch a web view.